# How to create a block view that displays content one year ago from from the post date of the current node

Tags: views

We have a surf report running on D6. One of the features that we'd like to add is a block on the node page of a surf report content-type that shows the surf report from one year ago.

I know how to create a filter that sets the date to one year from the current date/time, but I want to make this block display the report from one year from the *post date* of the current node (as opposed to current date/time).

Any ideas on this? I've racked my brain and can't think of any solutions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can [Views Data Rnage](http://drupal.org/project/views_daterange) be a useful module? There is another choice is [Views Date Range Filter D6](http://drupal.org/node/953364/release). You will have investigate both solution if they work for you.